# SSRS - How to get details of grouping on second line

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have data where the data set (table A) can have comments attached (table B).  There can be a one to many relationship between table A and B.  I have created an SSRS report which Groups by an employee (Parent CLient Partner) and then groups by nine additional fields.  For each of these groups, if comments exist, I want to display the Comments under the 9 field grouping.  The two fields in the attached image that I would like undereath are DateAdded and Comments.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Try moving your Comments field into a separate report called subComments and then add a subreport control to your main report. Make your subreport use subComments as the underlying report. Finally add parameters to your subreport to filter the comments data based on Parent Client Partner key.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS does have a `Lookup` function that allows you to get values from a different dataset. However, this is a suboptimal approach. It is usually much more efficient to do the data preparation in the SQL and let the report handle the presentation of the data.

In other words, join the comments to the data in a single dataset. It's OK for the other rows to be duplicated in the results because you can use the report grouping to control how the results are presented.

Comment: Thank you.  I have already queried the data joining both tables into one result.  In SSRS, I want the comments to go under the two groups I have created because the length of the comments can be 500 characters.  So my layout would look something like:

Comment: Partner (parent group)  ...   Client Name (child1 group) ... Business Name (child1 group) ... revenue (child1 group) ... and then Comments

Comment: @jbfiii Sounds like a plan. How did it work out for you?